# Processing data from React.js form with django

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I create a web application using Django for the back-end and React for the front-end. I have three input forms on my HTML page, which I create with react. I need to send this data to MySQL.db and processing using .py script. Can you explain, how can I send data from react to django

Comment: Could you please to check it - https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-an-app-with-react-and-django/

Answer (score 1):

With react, we mostly fetch data and show it as HTML, and that data is fetched by a web-based API, which just looks like a URL. so if you want to send data to Django must create an API with Django-rest-framework and it's very easy. You will need to send data to that API and it will add that to your database.